# Convert number into 7 bit words with 96 states max

Tags: encoding, binary, bit

I would like to encode some information in Code128 barcodes which allow 96 different characters to be used in one slot. Therefore, `95` decimal would translate to `101 1111b` and `96` to `1 000 0000b`.

Now I need an algorithm that converts a decimal (or binary) number into 7 bit words with 96 states at maximum. I sat here all morning trying to figure that algorithm out (playing with bit shifts and logarithms), but it seems that I'm missing some important point here.

How would I translate, for example, `537` (`10 0001 1001b`) into such words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing a bit with the numbers I finally found the solution. For `883.736`:

```
883.736 / 96 = 9.205 R: 56
  9.205 / 96 =    95 R: 85
     95 / 96 =     0 R: 95
```

Those numbers can be converted into 7 bit words. To get the original value:

```
883.736 = 56 * 96^0 + 85 * 96^1 + 95 * 96^2
```

**Algorithm expressed in C# (little endian):**

```
public static class Base96
{
  private const int BASE = 96;

  public static byte[] Encode(int number)
  {
    var list = new List<Byte>();

    do
    {
      list.Add((byte)(number % BASE));
    }
    while ((number = (number / BASE)) > 0);

    return list.ToArray();
  }

  public static int Decode(byte[] words)
  {
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
      result += (words[i] * (int)Math.Pow(BASE, i));
    }

    return result;
  }

}
```

Call like this:

```
var encoded = Base96.Encode(883736);
var decoded = Base96.Decode(encoded);
```

Answer (score 1):

Encoding arbitrary binary data into sequences with an alphabet of around 96 different letters is in general called [binary-to-text encoding or ASCII armor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/binary-to-text_encoding).

When your "binary" input byte stream is "short" and can potentially have any of the 256 possible bytes, but is mostly ASCII text (letters, numbers), it's most compact to let letters and numbers represent themselves (1 input byte to 1 output letter), reserving one or four "escape" symbols for bytes outside that range (expanding 1 "unusual byte" to 3 or 2 output letters), as in [percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/percent-encoding) or [quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/quoted-printable) encoding.

When your binary input byte stream has more-or-less equal frequencies for all 256 possible bytes (i.e., the stream has been encrypted or compressed or both), it's most compact to use some sort of [base-conversion algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/base_conversion) such as hexadecimal (expanding each octet to 2 hexadecimal digits) or [base32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32) (expanding 5 octets to 8 base32 digits) or [base64url](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/base64#URL_applications) (expanding 3 octets into 4 base64 digits) or [Z85](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85#ZeroMQ_Version_.28Z85.29) (expanding 4 octets into 5 base85 digits) or [baseE91](http://base91.sourceforge.net/) or [base95](http://www.icerealm.org/FTR/?s=docs&p=base95).

When your binary input byte stream has unequal frequencies (such as containing mostly ASCII text) or repetition, and is "long enough", it's most compact to first compress it (perhaps with [LZ4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ4_(compression_algorithm)) or [LZO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Oberhumer) or DEFLATE or [LZRW1-A](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Compression/Dictionary_compression#LZSS_and_LZRW1-A) ), creating a roughly equal-frequency compressed byte stream, and then encode that byte steam as above.