# C# - How to save byte values to file with smallest size possible?

Tags: c#, arrays, serialization

I need to serialize the following data in the smallest file size possible.

I have a collection of patterns, each pattern is a byte array (`byte[]`) of a set length.

In this example let's use a pattern length of 5, so byte array will be:

```
var pattern = new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Let's say we have 3 of the same pattern in a collection:

```
var collection = new byte[][] { pattern, pattern, pattern };
```

Currently I am saving the collection in an ASCII encoded file. Using the collection above, the saved file would look like this:

```
010203040501020304050102030405
```

Each byte in the array is represented by 2 digits (00) so that I can cater for byte values from 0 to 25, it can be visualized like this:

[01|02|03|04|05] [01|02|03|04|05] [01|02|03|04|05]

When I deserialize the file, I parse each block of 2 characters as a byte and put every 5 bytes into a byte array.

As I understand it, each character in the ASCII-encoded file is one byte - offering a possible 256 different values, but all I need is for each block of 2 characters to be a possible decimal value from 0 to 25.

When I save a file with 50,000 patterns, each with a length of 12, I end up with a 1.7MB file, which is way too big.

What encoding can I use in C# to make my file size much smaller?

Please provide example code of how to write and read this data to/from a file.

Comment: If your file doesn't have to be ASCII you could use [`ZipArchive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`ZipFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx) to compress the data.

Comment: Must the file be readable by a texteditor? You can save half the data by just saving the byte and not the digits.

Comment: Just as a general question, a gzip stream is out of question? Also no offense but this sounds alot like homework.

Comment: 0-25 -> A .. Z. or use a bitstream where every 5 bits denotes a value. Using a stream that does compression/decompression might be easier.

Comment: By writing in binary, you could compress up to 5 bits/number (log2(26) = 4.7)... but it is a pain writing bit based information

Comment: @Vulpex Homework? As in an assignment? No, it's for a puzzle game i'm making. I'm just a bit of a noob when it comes to this stuff.

Comment: @Hyarus No, it doesn't need to be readable by a text editor, but I don't know how to "just save the bytes".

Comment: @xanatos Sounds awesome, could you post an example?

Comment: @rene How would I serialize that data? If I serialize a char isn't that essentially still a byte? How would i read the data back? Could you post an example?

Comment: No, ASCII offers 128 values. And, no, `char` holds a UTF-16 code unit (_2_ bytes).

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar when encoding binary data into barcodes (see [Efficient compression and representation of key value pairs to be read from 1D barcodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269408/efficient-compression-and-representation-of-key-value-pairs-to-be-read-from-1d-b)). Consider the following code which will serialize samples into a file and deserialize them immediately:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var data = new List<byte[]>() {
        new byte[] { 01, 05, 15, 04, 11, 00, 01, 01, 05, 15, 04, 11, 00, 01 },
        new byte[] { 09, 04, 02, 00, 08, 12, 01, 07, 04, 02, 00, 08, 12, 01 },
        new byte[] { 01, 05, 06, 04, 02, 00, 01, 01, 05, 06, 04, 02, 00, 01 }
    };

    // has to be known when loading the file
    var reasonableBase = data.SelectMany(i => i).Max() + 1;

    using (var target = File.OpenWrite("data.bin"))
    {
        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(target))
        {
            // write the number of lines (16 bit, lines limited to 65536)
            writer.Write((ushort)data.Count);

            // write the base (8 bit, base limited to 255)
            writer.Write((byte)reasonableBase);

            foreach (var sample in data)
            {
                // converts the byte array into a large number of the known base (bypasses all the bit-mess)
                var serializedData = ByteArrayToNumberBased(sample, reasonableBase).ToByteArray();

                // write the length of the sample (8 bit, limited to 255)
                writer.Write((byte)serializedData.Length);
                writer.Write(serializedData);
            }
        }
    }

    var deserializedData = new List<byte[]>();

    using (var source = File.OpenRead("data.bin"))
    {
        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(source))
        {
            var lines = reader.ReadUInt16();
            var sourceBase = reader.ReadByte();

            for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
            {
                var length = reader.ReadByte();
                var value = new BigInteger(reader.ReadBytes(length));

                // chunk the bytes back of the big number we loaded
                // works because we know the base
                deserializedData.Add(NumberToByteArrayBased(value, sourceBase));
            }
        }
    }
}

private static BigInteger ByteArrayToNumberBased(byte[] data, int numBase)
{
    var result = BigInteger.Zero;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        result += data[i] * BigInteger.Pow(numBase, i);
    }

    return result;
}

private static byte[] NumberToByteArrayBased(BigInteger data, int numBase)
{
    var list = new List<Byte>();

    do
    {
        list.Add((byte)(data % numBase));
    }
    while ((data = (data / numBase)) > 0);

    return list.ToArray();
}
```

Compared to your format, the sample data will serialize to 27 bytes instead of 90. Using @xanatos's 4.7 bit per symbol, the perfect result would be `14 * 3 * 4.7 / 8 = 24,675 bytes`, so that's not bad (to be fair: the example serializes to 30 bytes with the base set to 26).

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, I'll have to take some time to look over it

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can use `GZipStream` and `BinaryFormatter` to read and write the data from and to a compressed file.

It is not very efficient for small arrays, but becomes more efficient for large arrays. However, note that this relies on the data being compressible - if it is not, then this will not be any use!

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace Demo
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var pattern    = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            var collection = new [] { pattern, pattern, pattern };

            string filename = @"e:\tmp\test.bin";
            zipToFile(filename, collection);

            var deserialised = unzipFromFile(filename);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", deserialised.Select(row => string.Join(", ", row))));
        }

        static void zipToFile(string file, byte[][] data)
        {
            using (var output = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))
            using (var gzip   = new GZipStream(output, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
            {
                new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(gzip, data);
            }
        }

        static byte[][] unzipFromFile(string file)
        {
            using (var input = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
            using (var gzip  = new GZipStream(input, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                return (byte[][]) new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(gzip);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes simplicity is the best compromise.

A rectangular array can be considered a sequence of linear arrays.

A file of bytes is a linear array of bytes.

Here is very simple code to convert a rectangular array of bytes and write bytes to a file:

```
// All patterns must be the same length so they can be split when reading
File.WriteAllBytes(Path.GetTempFileName(), collection.SelectMany(p => p).ToArray());
```

`System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany(pattern => pattern)` takes a sequence of sequences and flattens them to a sequence. (It along with ToArray() are not the most efficient but for 50,000 * 4 elements, it could be fine.)

Given that as a starting point, if compression is needed, Zip would be a way to go, as [shown by Matthew Watson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50346335/2226988).